# In the Symfony Dependency Injection Service, can I exclude all files in not ending in a specific suffix?

Tags: php, symfony, glob

We have been using the Symfony Dependency Injection Service for a while now, but we have to manually link each service to its interface.
I want to automate this via auto-wiring, but I have some problems with the exclude option.

I noticed providing multiple exclude paths was only possible in a later version, so I updated to the latest version that my current PHP version can support (v5.4).

Now I can provide a list of paths successfully, but I don't know how I can provide a path that has a negation in it.
The documentation mentions that exclude options can be any valid glob pattern, but even though I believe my glob pattern is valid it does not work.

I want to exclude all non-repository classes from my domain folder, for example

- Domain/Repository/IUserRepository.php => should not be excluded
- Domain/Repository/UserRepository/UserDTO.php => should be excluded

I have tried using patterns like:

- Domain/**/!(*Repository.php)
- Domain/**/!(*Repository).php
- Domain/**/[!]*Repository.php

But when debugging inside the code, when translating the patterns to a regex it carries over the "!" character raw.

Is there a way to exclude all non-repository classes from inside the Domain folder using a single glob pattern that is handled by Symfony?

---

**Edit:** I have found a raised issue and PR on their GitHub that was rejected: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/35737

It sounds like they either think it'll impact performance too much or they want to wait until they can integrate more glob pattern "variants" at once.

If anyone still has a solution for me that would be great, but right now I'm leaning towards exclude everything but the "Repository" folder and renaming/moving all other files inside to have the DTO suffix and exclude those.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close! Try this:

```
Domain/**/*[!Repository].php
```

if you don't want the repository classes, and

```
Domain/**/*Repository.php
```

if you do want the repository claases

You can play around with this glob pattern tester here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=Domain%2F%2A%2A%2F%2A%5B%21Repository%5D.php&matches=false&tests=Domain%2FRepository%2FIUserRepository.php&tests=Domain%2FRepository%2FUserRepository%2FUserDTO.php

Comment: Hi, I had been using this site to test my patterns: https://globster.xyz/

I tried your pattern, but I had the same issue. ! and [ characters are not recognized as special and are just added to the regex.